# Bootstrap 4 Grid Misalignment Only On Small Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I'm trying to put a checkbox next to a "button" that is really a styled `<a>` tag. The checkbox is completely independent from the button, which is just a link. I need the link to be on the same row as the checkbox. When the page is wide enough to show my outermost col-sm-6 beside its sibling col-sm-6, everything is okay. But when you shrink the window enough that the first col-sm-6 appears on top of (not to the left of) the second col-sm-6, the checkbox starts to take up an entire row by itself.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfgodb9d/6/

Shrink the window to see the ugly layout and expand it to see an okay layout.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="verticalActionButtonGroup">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              the checkbox goes here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              the button-styled link goes here
            </div>

      ... and so forth until you hit a sibling col-sm-6...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `col-sm-3` use `col-3` and instead of `col-sm-9` use `col-9`

Please note that in BS4 there is no extra small `xs-*` class

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfgodb9d/7/)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In place of **col-sm-6** use only **col-6**. In Bootsrap 4, **.col-sm-** (small devices - screen width >= 576px). If you want to use for less than 576px width then use **.col-** (extra small devices - screen width < 576px). Both **col-6** will be always in one row at any small device.